# iTunes URL to your app list doesn't work on iOS8.4

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, url-scheme, ios8.4

iTunes URL to your app list like https://itunes.apple.com/artist/id445795301 doesn't work on iOS8.4.

When you open links on iOS8.4, it opens Apple Music.. Does anyone know the way to fix this?